# Lazy Loading and Javascript with Reveal.js

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio, reveal.js

I am making a slideshow with Reveal.js. According to the docs (https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js/), you are supposed to use **data-src** for lazy loading. How can I utilize lazy loading and play the audio with JS?

This is what I tried but it didn't play the audio:

```
 <section>
    <audio id="audio2" controls><source data-src="http://opengameart.org/sites/default/files/foom_0.wav" type="audio/wav"></audio>
    <script>
        var x = document.getElementById("audio2"); 
        x.play(); 
    </script>
 </section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script is executed at the time the presentation is loaded, at which time presumably the lazy loading hasn't happened yet and so the file cannot be played.

If you want to automatically play the audio file when the slide is shown, you should run your `x.play()` in the callback of the [event emitted by Reveal upon showing the slide](https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js/#slide-changed-event):

```
Reveal.addEventListener( 'slidechanged', function( event ) {
    if (event.indexh === mySlideNumberWithAudio) { // might need to check indexv too
        document.getElementById("audio2").play(); 
    }
} );
```